# Problems with cursor position in canvas, wrapped in jquery tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, canvas, tabs, fabricjs

I have a canvas, which I set to freedraw mode using fabric.js. I want to show this canvas in a separate tab (jQuery UI Tabs).
My problem is that when I try to draw, my cursor is somewhere to the top left of the dot, that I try to draw on canvas.

When I do not use tabs, the situation with cursor and dot doesn`t happen.

Does somebody know, what is this and how to cure it?

Unfortunately, I didn't manage to duplicate the situation in jsfiddle, since, as I've understood, there's no jquery-ui and I cannot use two frameworks at once.

In general the code is as follows:

```js
$("#mainWindow").tabs();
var r_draw;
var r = function() {
  r_draw = new fabric.Canvas('cC', {
    isDrawingMode: true
  });
  r_draw.freeDrawingBrush.color = "#005e7a";
  r_draw.freeDrawingBrush.width = 5;
  r_draw.freeDrawingBrush.shadowColor = "#ff0000";
  r_draw.freeDrawingBrush.shadowWidth = 8;
  r_draw.freeDrawingBrush.shadowWidth = 12;
};
r();
```

```css
.info {
  border: 4px double rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 17px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 17px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 17px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

```html
<div id='mainWindow'>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabA">A</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabB">B</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabC">C</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabA">//some stuff A</div>
  <div id="tabB">//some stuff B</div>
  <div id='tabC'>
    <canvas id='cC' class="info" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
    <br />
    <button id='bC'>Button4C</button>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a jsfiddle including jQuery UI and fabricjs: http://jsfiddle.net/05en5vop/

Comment: Thank you! And what is bad, that the described behaviour doesn't show itself. What am I missing to show the problem correctly? Any suggestions? I

Comment: If possible, provide direct online link to your website where this issue can be checked. It sounds like a problem with how elements are positionned but that's just an idea

Comment: there is no website right now... it's on local server

Comment: But is it really all the code you are using? No other HTML elements? CSS? javascript/jQuery? Plugin? Etc... Could you at least take a screenshot to make your issue clearer?

Comment: and the positioning is not more complicated, as shown here: I do not set sizes or positions, but when I added  align="center" to the tabC div, the situation became fully unbearable - the dot dissappeared, but the console shows no error and the freedrawing mode works fine, as the cursor changes to the cross on canvas.

Comment: Maybe try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656272/mouse-offset-in-canvas-fabric-js ?

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! That worked! Looks like I didn't manage to formulate my problem well ))).